# hist distribution using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I plot a vector distribution with qplot that I don't know its distribution in advance, it's calculated in a function. I just know that the x values are between 0 and 1.

I use the below command line and get the attached histogram.

As the distribution is jammed, how can I make it more spread so that the distribution becomes clear? which parameters to use or other functions that produce histogram?

Moreover how to color so that the bins becomes more distiguishable?

keeping the color legend may or may not be necessary.

```
qplot(my.vec,binwidth = .2)+ 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = .2, aes(fill = ..count..), colour='black', fill='skyblue')
```

[image]

Another example:
[image]

Comment: Reduce the value passed to `binwidth`? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: your vector seems to be between 0.4 and 0.8, so if you use bin with of .2 you end up with 2 bins...

Comment: This is another example with binwidth = .1. But I think it doesn't much help.

That's the problem. if the vector is btw .4 and .8 even with  binwidth = .1, it won't be better. For these values whose freq are so close together, how to make the distribution more spread or somehow more distinguisable?

I don't want to reduce too much binwidth for ex .05 because I have other hists to plot in the same row, so I don't want to use up much the graphics width and on the other hand, a small binwidth may be good for 1 hist and not for another plotted on the same device.

Answer (score 0):

To "unjam" the plot, use `xlim`:

```
qplot(x) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2, aes(fill = ..count..), colour='black', fill='skyblue') + xlim(0,1)
```

I'm not sure why you want to use variation in color here when column height is already giving you that information. That's the whole point of a histogram, and then you don't have to worry about confusing color-blind people. So why not just:

```
qplot(x) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2, colour='black', fill='skyblue') + xlim(0,1)
```

Here's the toy data I used to test it:

```
x <- c(0.41, 0.42, 0.47, 0.47, 0.49, 0.50, 0.51, 0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.59, 0.61, 0.62, 0.65, 0.68, 0.69, 0.70, 0.75, 0.78, 0.79)
```

And here's a .png of the plot I got:

[image]

Comment: when I use similar to your code, I get
`qplot(x) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2, colour='black', fill='white') + xlim(0.4,1)
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.`
the bars at the left of histogram are black and the one in the middle is white. Why?


Moreover, I want to draw a dashed vertical line starting from y=0 to the max count of bars and not to the top of the histogram
should I use geom_abline or geom_vline? Suppose I want to draw from x=.75, y= 0 to x=.75 to y = 9

Comment: I think that gets overridden by the `geom_histogram()` part and therfore doesn't affect the output, but: does that go away if you put `binwidth=0.2` back into the call to `qplot()`, so `qplot(x, binwidth=0.2) + geom...`?

Comment: yes, it does. but why do I get a legend with black blue color for counts when I use `aes(fill = ..count..)` and `colour='black', fill='white'`? What to do to get the same color in the legend as the bars in the histogram?

Comment: I'm not following what you're trying to do with the legend and column colors. Can you be clearer, please? Are you trying to use multiple colors with a legend (which doesn't really make sense for a histogram, but...), or just to control the fill color?

Comment: just to fill the histogram bars' color, like the one illustrated above, frequency is depicted from 0 to 2 or 0 to 50. So when I use the aforementioned script, the bars of histogram are filled with white but the color legend is from black to blue!

Comment: So why not just leave out the `aes(fill = ..count..)` part, and thus the legend, too?

Comment: You're bundling a lot of different questions into this post. If there are other issues you can't resolve, better to open new questions for them.