# Draw a vertical line on a histogram plotted by qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

On A histogram, I want to draw a dashed vertical line starting from y=0 to the max count of bars of a histogram and not to the top of the histogram and also starting from 0 and not below 0. Should I use `geom_abline` or `geom_vline`? Suppose I want to draw from x=.75, y= 0 to x=.75 to y = 9 on a histogram plotted in

[hist distribution using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698858/hist-distribution-using-ggplot2/31699754?noredirect=1#comment51394119_31699754)

Comment: probably `geom_segment`

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possibility, using the data from the example that you mentioned:

```
my.vec <-c(0.41, 0.42, 0.47, 0.47, 0.49, 0.50, 0.51, 0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.59, 0.61, 0.62, 0.65, 0.68, 0.69, 0.70, 0.75, 0.78, 0.79)
p <- qplot(my.vec,binwidth = .2) +  
    geom_histogram(binwidth = .2, aes(fill =..count..), colour='black') + 
    geom_segment(aes(x =.75, y = 0, xend = .75, yend = 9), linetype="dashed",  color="red")
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to draw the segment to the top of histogram, here, to the max of light blue bar which is perhaps 9.75 but without knowing in advance this value, i.e max of `yend`?

Comment: Somehow, the max of histogram counts should be calculated in order to be used for `yend`. Some thing equivalent to

`my.hist= hist(my.vec, plot=F)`
`max.count= max(my.hist$count)`